# Magento 2 - How to get minimal price of associated simple price of Grouped Product in phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, phtml, simple-product, associated-products

I made the `custom phtml` and I have `custom product collection`. I just need to show the `minimal price` of `associated simple product` of grouped product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First get child IDS from this function getChildrenIds($parentId, $required = true)

Comment: Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this code in your phtml file. Variable `lowest price` has the minimal price.

```
$lowestprice = 0; $count = 0;
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {

    $usedProds = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($usedProds as $child) {
        if ($child->getId() != $_product->getId()) {
            if ($count == 0){
                $lowestprice = $child->getPrice();
            }

            if ($child->getPrice() < $lowestprice){
                $lowestprice = $child->getPrice();
            }
        }
      $count++;
    }
    $finalPrice = $lowestprice;
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: let me try this and I will get back to you

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

Comment: Glad it helped.